# java.lang.SecurityException: Signers of org.bouncycastle.util.Encodable

Tags: java, java-8, tokens, jar

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class PruebaFirmaUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            
            String token = "token";
            String pwdKeyStore = "password";
            
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, pwdKeyStore.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] chain = (Certificate[]) keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
            
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) chain[0];
            
            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(token.getBytes());
            List<X509Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(cert);
            
            Store<?> certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
            
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(key);
            
            ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            v.add(getSigningCertificateV2(cert, "SHA-256", true));
            
            AttributeTable signedAtributtesTable = new AttributeTable(v);
            signedAtributtesTable.toASN1EncodableVector();
            
            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                    new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder (new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
                            .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(signedAtributtesTable))
                            .build(sha256Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(cert.getEncoded())));

            gen.addCertificates(certs);

            CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);
            
            System.out.println(sigData.getEncoded());
            
            
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CMSException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static Attribute getSigningCertificateV2(final X509Certificate cert, final String digestAlgorithmName, 
            final boolean doNotIncludePolicyOnSignigCertificate) {
        
        SigningCertificate scv = null;
        
        try {
            final GeneralName gn = new GeneralName(X500Name.getInstance(cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getEncoded()));
            final GeneralNames gns = new GeneralNames(gn);
            
            final IssuerSerial isuerSerial = new IssuerSerial(gns, cert.getSerialNumber());
            
            final byte[] certHash = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgorithmName).digest(cert.getEncoded());
            final ESSCertID essCertID = new ESSCertID(certHash, isuerSerial);
            
            
            final PolicyInformation[] polInfo = doNotIncludePolicyOnSignigCertificate ? null : getPolicyInformation(cert);
            
            if(polInfo != null && polInfo.length > 0) {
                final ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
                v.add(new DERSequence(essCertID));
                v.add(new DERSequence(polInfo));
                scv = SigningCertificate.getInstance(new DERSequence(new DERSequence(polInfo)));
            } else {
                scv = new SigningCertificate(essCertID);
            }
            
                    
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificateV2, new DERSet(scv));
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static PolicyInformation[] getPolicyInformation(final X509Certificate cert) {
        if(cert == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El certificado no puede ser nulo");
        }
        
        final byte[] certificatePoliciesBytes = cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32");
        if(certificatePoliciesBytes == null || certificatePoliciesBytes.length < 1) {
            return new PolicyInformation[0];
        }
        
        return (CertificatePolicies.getInstance(
                ASN1Sequence.getInstance(
                        ASN1OctetString.getInstance(
                                certificatePoliciesBytes).getOctets())))
                .getPolicyInformation();
    }

}
```

Cuando ejecuto me da el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Signers of
> 'org.bouncycastle.util.Encodable' do not match signers of other
> classes in package    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageSigners(ClassLoader.java:454)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:379)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:360)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:730)     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:96)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1187)     at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:739)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:605)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:937)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:882)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:865)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)

Utilizo las siguientes librerías:

> -bcmail-jdk15on-1.49
>
> -bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52
>
> -bcprov-jdk15on-1.52
>
> -org.opensmarthouse.core.io.jetty.certificate-0.10.1

He utilizado otras versiones pero siguiente fallando. Puede que no haya encontrado la correcta.

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: puedes comprobar que no tienes ninguna libreria de bouncy duplicada? Aunque sean diferentes versiones? Qué IDE estás utilizando? En caso de que sea eclipse cambia el orden de import de las librerias e importa primero -bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52

Comment: Utilizo eclipse. He eliminado -bcmail-jdk15on-1.49 que no me hacía falta. He cambiado el orden de los import pero sigue fallando

Comment: Corrijo: era -org.opensmarthouse.core.io.jetty.certificate-0.10.1 la que dio problemas.